# ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't show items from Online JSON but it does from local JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, simplecursoradapter

As the title say, i'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter to fill a ListView from a MatrixCursor. When i use the url from my Wamp MySql Server(local) it works but when i change to the url from my MySql remote server it doesn't show the items.
Please notice that the Toast is always working as it means that the cursor is not empty in both cases. No error are displayed in logs
My main class:

```
public class ActivityPista extends AppCompatActivity {    
    private String url = "http://192.168.1.129/tutorialpistas/GetPistas.php";/**This one works**/
    //private String url = "http://*********.com/archivosconnect/getPistas.php";/**This one doesn't**/
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private String[] columnasBD = new String[] {"_id", "nombre", "municipio", "direccion", "numpistas", "cubierto"};
    private MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnasBD);
    private ListView listado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_pista_activity);

    listado = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaPistas);

    //Iniciate connection
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    //Get Json and fill the cursor
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {                
            try {
                JSONArray pistas = response.getJSONArray("pistas");
                if (pistas != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pistas.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject pista = pistas.getJSONObject(i);
                        cursor.addRow(new Object[]{
                                pista.getString("_id"),
                                pista.getString("nombre"),
                                pista.getString("municipio"),
                                pista.getString("direccion"),
                                pista.getString("numpistas"),
                                pista.getString("cubierto")
                        });
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numero: " + (i+1) + " = " + pista.getString("nombre"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//This toast always works
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.append(error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    //Add requestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    //Set the adapter      
    final String[] desdeEstasColumnas = {"nombre", "municipio", "direccion", "numpistas", "cubierto"};

    int[] aEstasViews = {R.id.textview_item_pista_nombre, R.id.textview_item_pista_municipio, R.id.textview_item_pista_direccion,
            R.id.boton_item_pista_num, R.id.boton_item_pista_cubierta};

    final SimpleCursorAdapter mArrayAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_lista_pista, cursor, desdeEstasColumnas, aEstasViews, 0);
    listado.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);       
}
```

}

Here is item_lista_pista.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/marco"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_lista_pistas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_item_pista"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@mipmap/menu_pista2"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_item_pista_nombre"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/nombre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/fuente_grande"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_item_pista_municipio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/municipio"
                style="@style/fuente_normal"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_item_pista_direccion"
                android:hint="@string/direccion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/fuente_normal"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pistas"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_item_pista_num"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/marco"
                android:hint="@string/numpistas"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cubierto"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_item_pista_cubierta"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/marco"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/cubierto"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTestPistas"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally list_pista_activity.xml with the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listaPistas"/>
```

Any help would be appreciate :)

Comment: have you confirmed data actually comes back from the Request? and do you have the Internet permission defined in your manifest?

Comment: Yes both, the data is coming as i can see the toast working and showing every item and i defined the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Finally i got it!! i solved it declaring the SimpleCursorAdapter outside the onCreate and calling mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() just after have filled the cursor